# Why doesn't Mockito's when()... thenReturn() work with string constants from other classes

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to stub a getExtras() call on a mocked intent but it seems when()...thenReturn() doesn't work (returns NULL) when I use any of the TelephonyManager string constants. I've tried using dummy strings and it works so I know the test isn't working because of the when()...thenReturn() calls.

Here's my code

```
package metabrick.com.notrightnow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import metabrick.com.notrightnow.CatchingMissedCallsFeature.MissedCallBroadcastReceiver;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertSame;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)


/*This class tests the logic of MissedallBroadcastReceiver class logic .i.e
* The logic of detecting a missed phone call*/

public class MissedCallBroadcastReceiverTest  {
@Mock private Context context;
@Mock private Intent intent;
@Mock Bundle bundle ;

private MissedCallBroadcastReceiver missedCallBroadcastReceiver;

@Before
public void setUpMissedCallBroadcastReceiver(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    missedCallBroadcastReceiver = new MissedCallBroadcastReceiver();

}
@Test
public void onReceiveTest(){
    when(intent.getStringExtra(anyString()))
          .thenReturn(telephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING);

    when(intent.getExtras()).thenReturn(bundle);

    when(bundle.getString("incoming_number")).thenReturn("905-456-4520");

    //Calling onReceive
    missedCallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);

    //Verfy that attempt was made to retrieve the state of the phone
    verify(intent).getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    //verfy that an attempt was made to retrievr the number of the caller
    verify(bundle).getString("incoming_number");


    /*Testing a received call scenario */
    when(intent.getStringExtra(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
            .thenReturn(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK);
    missedCallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);
    //check that the callRinging variable is set to true
    assertTrue(missedCallBroadcastReceiver.isCallRinging());
    //check that the callReceived variable is set to true
    assertTrue(missedCallBroadcastReceiver.isCallReceived());

    /*Testing a missed call scenario */
    when(intent.getStringExtra(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
            .thenReturn(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE);
    missedCallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context, intent);
    //check that the callReceived and ringing variables are set to false
    assertFalse(missedCallBroadcastReceiver.isCallReceived());
    assertFalse(missedCallBroadcastReceiver.isCallRinging());

    // checking that the number gotten from the intent
    assertSame("905-456-4520", missedCallBroadcastReceiver.getCallerNumber());




}
```

}

---

Here's the method under test

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Getting the phone state
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state == null) return;

    //Getting the caller's number
    callerNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number");

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) rang = true;
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) callReceived = true;

    //if the phone is idle
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        if (ringing&&!callReceived){

            ringing = false;

           try{
               Toast.makeText(context, "Missed call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
        callReceived = false;
    }


}
```

I've searched for a while now I can't find any answers and I don't know how else to stub the intent for these calls to getExtras(). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where are you facing the issue?Are your verification statements working fine?

Comment: @codeLover the when()...theReturn() lines don't work, the intent is returning NULL instead of what it's stubbed to return. Yes the verification statement work fine.